# FuncAnimation increase FPS for long animations?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I'm working on 'translating' my C program to python. It is a damped simple harmonic motion of a particle on the y-axis. The animation uses FuncAnimation from matplotlib. It uses small step sizes (dh) for every step (frame) so that the particle's path is accurately represented. 
The problem with small dh, it increases the number of frames per unit distance. Is there way to increase the frames per second so that the animations goes faster(higher fps) for small dh?

By the way, the program uses 2D arrays for future improvement like using more than one particle. However, I have yet to incorporate a method to animate all particles, but this is not the issue.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

#The bungee rope has to have a [k = 0.15] in order to do 5 oscillations
N = 1
dt = 0.1 #//size step
time = 8000
count =1;
b = 1;
k = 0.2;
m= 100;

# function to open an x-window
fig = plt.figure()

#define positions and velocities for each
x = np.zeros((N,time))
y = np.zeros((N,time))
vx = np.zeros((N,time))
vy = np.zeros((N,time))

#define variables for the plotting canvas
xmin = -5.0; xmax =5.0;
ymin = -80.0; ymax = 80.0;

ax = plt.axes(xlim= (xmin,xmax), ylim=(ymin,ymax),ylabel = 'Y Position')
(my_point,) = ax.plot([],[],'ro',ms=7) #stored var to make red circle (ro) point


#set initial position and velocity
x[:N,0] = 0; y[:N,0] = 75;
vx[:N,0] = 0; vy[:N,0] = 0.0;

for i in range(time-1):
    #set path/function
    for j in range(N):
        a = (-k*y[j,i] - b*vy[j,i])/(m); #damped simple harmonic motion
        vy[j,i+1] = vy[j,i] +  a*dt #differential changes to velocity
        y[j,i+1] = y[j,i] + dt*vy[j,i+1] #differential changes to distance

def get_step(n,x,y,point):
    point.set_data(x[n],y[n])

mymovie = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,get_step,frames= time,\
                                  fargs=(x[0,:],y[0,:],my_point), interval = 0)   

plt.show()
print("For 5 oscillations k = %f\n" % k)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `interval` of the animation is already set to 0, meaning in theory an infinite number of frames per second. In reality it means that the animation is drawn as fast as your computer allows it to.

The limiting factor in the animation is that for each frame everything in the canvas is redrawn. This is a lot of overhead, since axes, ticks, labels etc. all stay the same during animation. A standard technique to overcome this limitation is blitting. This would only repaint the animated artist (the red ball) in each frame.

```
def get_step(n,x,y,point):
    point.set_data(x[n],y[n])
    return point,

mymovie = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,get_step,frames= time, blit=True,\
                                  fargs=(x[0,:],y[0,:],my_point), interval = 1)
```

If this is not fast enough, you might consider skipping steps of your animation, e.g. showing only every second step,

```
frames = time[::2]
```